# Finding Synonym library

Tags: elasticsearch, shared-libraries, synonym

I have been using synonym in Elasticsearch to map data. I have created a index setting like this

```
PUT uk-2016.06.22
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ 
            "british,uk,england,britain"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rather than created manually a library txt document in mapping synonyms, is there any synonym library available for downloading to map data for elasticsearch application? Because it seems difficult for me to find one.

Comment: A synonym can be anything and will depend on your use case and what you consider to be valid synonyms in your context. Maybe you should explain in a little more details what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it helps to explain clearer. Thanks

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid :) Please explain the use case you're trying to implement.

Comment: I am trying to creating synonym for different places in UK, and to make the searching more flexible. For example, another synonym would be like "manchester, MU, Man City, Man United". Then, if I ingest different document data into ES, when I go through searching the index, it will show whatever results related to manchester even if I just type MU

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for an existing synonym file for UK cities. I'm not certain such a file exists, though, as it will depend on what the author of that file would consider to be a synonym of each city name and that might differ from your conception of city synonyms.